# Proper way of obtaining the DBConnection for a Web Application

Tags: java, jdbc

We have a Web Application which will serve more than 1000 concurrent users 
Currently , the Utility class for obtaining the DB Connnection is

```
public static Connection getDBConnection()
       {
          Connection conn = null;
          try
          {
             InitialContext ctx = new InitialContext();
             DataSource ds = (DataSource) ctx.lookup("java:/comp/env/jdbc/MyLocalDB");
             try
             {
                conn = ds.getConnection();
             }
             catch ( SQLException sqlEx )
             {
                System.out.println( "cannot get JDBC connection: " + sqlEx ); 
             }
          }
          catch ( NamingException nEx )
          {
             nEx.printStackTrace();
          }
          return conn;
       }
```

**Option 2 :**

```
 public class DBConnection2 {
    private static DataSource dataSource;
    static {
        try {
              dataSource = (DataSource) new InitialContext().lookup("java:/comp/env/jdbc/MyLocalDB");
        } catch (NamingException e) {
            try {
                throw new Exception("'jndifordbconc' not found in JNDI",e);
            } catch (Exception e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    public static Connection getConnection() {
        try {
            return dataSource.getConnection();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }

    }

}
```

Please let me know whats the better option (I guess its second operation as lookup is a costly operation and i am doing it only for once in a application .)

please share your views .

Comment: What container are you using and what kind of application is this? If you are using Java EE (or Spring), you can use EJBs in which there is no need to manually obtain a connection using a JNDI look up. They are also transactional handling database transactions on their own and many more. (In the current first case, you are doing a JNDI look up on every call to the `getDBConnection()` method which I would not prefer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should adopt the second approach. As you say you don't need to keep looking up the datasource in JNDI.

I am assuming that you are using a pooled data source as provided by the tomcat-jdbc project, otherwise performance will be terrible.

Answer (score 1):

On the second approach you should be sure to use connection pooling. Otherwise users will have to wait for others.

For example To *Tomcat* brings it own connection pool.
Or if you don't use Tomcat maybe you could have a look at [C3p0: JDBC DataSources/Resource Pools](http://sourceforge.net/projects/c3p0/).

see: [Instantiating and Configuring a ComboPooledDataSource](http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/#using_combopooleddatasource)

Comment: i am using tomcat connection pooling and configured the following under the server.xml <Resource name="jdbc/MyDB"
      global="jdbc/MyDB"
      type="javax.sql.DataSource"
      driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
      url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/OMS_RES4"
    factory="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceFactory"
      username="root"
      password=""
   initialSize="10"
      maxActive="100"
      maxIdle="20"
     minIdle="10"
   suspectTimeout="60"
   timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis="30000"
   minEvictableIdleTimeMillis="60000"
 />

Answer (score 0):

The second option initialize `dataSource` only once when the class is loaded, then it is shared around all `DBConnection2` instances. The first option initialize a new `DataSource` instance every time you call `getDBConnection()`. Thus the second option has better performance. But please be pay attention to connection release issue. Make sure close the connection if you choose the first option. I prefer use a framework to handle DB connection, like `Spring JDBC`: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/jdbc.html